# Rename & Copy Multiple Files (Different names) to One Name With Numbers

Tags: batch-rename

how can I rename or copy multiple files (with different name without numbers like "jhf.mp4" "JJHGF.flv" ..) to one name with numbers like (input_01.mp4 input_02 ....) (order by case)  by batch file by giving just path of (folder files) to batch file or dropping the files to it (patch file).
-- MEAN USING VARIABLE OR (dropping with %*) .

Note 1: I need this technique for encoding animes with X264 if any other good ideas I'll be happy to hear it.

Note 2: I'm using Windows 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can solve this problem using WSHost-scripts. WSHost-system should be preinstalled on any modern Windows computer.

---

I designed a system of utilities to tackle your problem:

1. **build-mapping-to-normalized-filenames.js**
2. **map-filenames.js**
3. **cleanup.cmd**
4. **before.cmd**
5. **after.cmd**

You can find source code for 3-4-5 at the bottom of this answer, and for 1-2 - in separate answers (there is a limit of characters per answer).

1 and 2 are workhorses of this system. Powerful but not user-friendly. Yes you can use them as stand-alone utilities if you understand what input they use.

3-4-5 - are glue that bind this system and expose user-friendly controls.

This system is dependent on absolute paths. But all absolute paths are set as variables at the start of 3-4-5 - so if you want to reorganize system - you need change things there and only there.

This is how it should be deployed at filesystem:

```
folders:
C:\1\     <- this is the root of system
C:\1\aOrig    <- folder for original files
C:\1\norm\    <- folder with files that are part of this system + temp folders
C:\1\norm\backend   <- place for non-user-friendly utilities

files:
C:\1\norm\backend\build-mapping-to-normalized-filenames.js
C:\1\norm\backend\map-filenames.js
C:\1\norm\after.cmd
C:\1\norm\before.cmd
C:\1\norm\cleanup.cmd

+files: (these are example international filesnames that you can use for playground to check how system works to make yourserf familiar with it)
C:\1\aOrig\English.txt     <- test files, you could add unique content to each
C:\1\aOrig\Русский.txt
C:\1\aOrig\العربية.txt
C:\1\aOrig\ܐܪܡܝܐ.txt
C:\1\aOrig\中文.txt
C:\1\aOrig\日本語.txt
```

---

### How to use it:

You open your console and go to dir **C:\1\norm**

You call programs in this order:

1. cleanup.cmd
2. before.cmd
3. What happened now is that two interesting temp folders are created:

   - **C:\1\norm\bTemp** <- here are normalized files.
   - **C:\1\norm\mappingTemp** <- it contains a file with mapping between original and normalized names.

   What you must do now - is to process files in **C:\1\norm\bTemp** - that special processing you mentioned before. Right now for the purposes of learning, you can manually change extensions and contents.
4. after.cmd
5. cleanup.cmd

And that's it.

So, if we condence it that's your typical session here, plain and simple -

```
cleanup.cmd
before.cmd
..do your stuff with files at "C:\1\norm\bTemp"...
after.cmd
cleanup.cmd
```

Also, you don't need command line to use those - you can open **C:\1\norm** in Explorer and double click those utilities in the order that I explained above - cleanup-before-(..manually do your work with bTemp..)-after-cleanup

---

Listing for program **cleanup.cmd** :

```
@ECHO OFF

:: name of this script...
:: useful for debugging...
SET me=%~nx0

:: aOrig - directory that contains source files...
:: bTemp - temporary working directory...
:: mTemp - temporary directory for mapping.txt...
SET aOrig=C:\1\aOrig
SET bTemp=C:\1\norm\bTemp
SET mTemp=C:\1\norm\mappingTemp


:: Removing temporary folders...
:: Be warned - this RD is working
:: in quiet mode /Q - so it wouldn't ask you politely
:: about del y/n - thus, please make shure that
:: %aOrig% doesn't point to anything
:: important for your personal data or system...
    IF EXIST "%bTemp%" RD /S /Q "%bTemp%"
    IF EXIST "%mTemp%" RD /S /Q "%mTemp%"

    IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 (
        ECHO Script %me% failed on step cleanup-1: [Removing temporary folders]...
        ECHO Error: %ERRORLEVEL%
        EXIT /B 1
    )

:: Successfully finished
    ECHO.
    ECHO Script %me% successfully finished!
```

---

Listing for program **before.cmd** :

```
@ECHO OFF

:: name of this script...
:: useful for debugging...
SET me=%~nx0

:: aOrig - directory that contains original files...
:: bTemp - temporary working directory...
:: mTemp - temporary directory for mapping.txt...
SET aOrig=C:\1\aOrig
SET bTemp=C:\1\norm\bTemp
SET mTemp=C:\1\norm\mappingTemp

:: scriptBuild - name of .js-script for building a map
::               from original to normalized filenames...
:: scriptMapFi - name of .js-script interpreting
::               mapping file that was build by scriptBuild...
:: mappingFile - path for file that will contain mapping between
::               original filenames and normalized filenames...
SET scriptBuild=C:\1\norm\backend\build-mapping-to-normalized-filenames.js
SET scriptMapFi=C:\1\norm\backend\map-filenames.js
SET mappingFile=C:\1\norm\mappingTemp\mapping.txt

:: creating temporary folders...
    IF NOT EXIST "%bTemp%" MKDIR "%bTemp%"
    IF NOT EXIST "%mTemp%" MKDIR "%mTemp%"
    IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 (
        ECHO Script %me% failed on step before-1: [Creating temporary folders]...
        ECHO Error: %ERRORLEVEL%
        EXIT /B 1
    )

:: now we run build-mapping-to-normalized-filenames.js ...
:: that //U thing is important...
    CSCRIPT //U //NoLogo "%scriptBuild%" "%aOrig%" 0 1 > "%mappingFile%"
    IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 (
        ECHO Script %me% failed on step before-2: [Building a list of normalized filenames]...
        ECHO Error: %ERRORLEVEL%
        EXIT /B 1
    )

:: now we run map-filenames.js ...
:: that //U thing is important...
    CSCRIPT //U //NoLogo "%scriptMapFi%" "%aOrig%" "%bTemp%" /NotTraining < "%mappingFile%"
    IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 (
        ECHO Script %me% failed on step before-3: [Copy files while simultaneously changing their names to normalised form]...
        ECHO Error: %ERRORLEVEL%
        EXIT /B 1
    )

:: Successfully finished
    ECHO.
    ECHO Script %me% successfully finished!
```

---

Listing for program **after.cmd** :

```
@ECHO OFF

:: name of this script...
:: useful for debugging...
SET me=%~nx0

:: aOrig - directory that contains original files...
:: bTemp - temporary working directory...
:: mTemp - temporary directory for mapping.txt...
SET aOrig=C:\1\aOrig
SET bTemp=C:\1\norm\bTemp
SET mTemp=C:\1\norm\mappingTemp

:: scriptBuild - name of .js-script for building a map
::               from original to normalized filenames...
:: scriptMapFi - name of .js-script interpreting
::               mapping file that was build by scriptBuild...
:: mappingFile - path for file that will contain mapping between
::               original filenames and normalized filenames...
SET scriptBuild=C:\1\norm\backend\build-mapping-to-normalized-filenames.js
SET scriptMapFi=C:\1\norm\backend\map-filenames.js
SET mappingFile=C:\1\norm\mappingTemp\mapping.txt

:: Removing files in original folder...
:: Not recursive
:: Be warned - this DEL is working
:: in quiet mode /Q - so it wouldn't ask you politely
:: about del y/n - thus, please make shure that
:: %aOrig% doesn't point to anything
:: important for your personal data or system...
    IF EXIST "%aOrig%" DEL /Q "%aOrig%"

    IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 (
        ECHO Script %me% failed on step after-1: [Removing files from original folder]...
        ECHO Error: %ERRORLEVEL%
        EXIT /B 1
    )

:: now we run map-filenames.js ...
:: that //U thing is important...
    CSCRIPT //U //NoLogo "%scriptMapFi%" "%bTemp%" "%aOrig%" /NotTraining /MapFrom2To1 /ResultExtension:2 /FuzzyExtensionsFrom < "%mappingFile%"
    IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 (
        ECHO Script %me% failed on step after-2: [Copy files while simultaneously changing their names to normalised form]...
        ECHO Error: %ERRORLEVEL%
        EXIT /B 1
    )

:: Successfully finished
    ECHO.
    ECHO Script %me% successfully finished!
```

Comment: it works thanks . can i Restore the original names to files (you told that the names is linked) because (input-.. is work name when i finished with it i want rastore the original name in last of patch file) and i would like the first Number is Variable (can changed) (if not possible just put 1) and algorithm for leading zeroes be 0 by default. THanks & I'm sorry for much questions.

Comment: @ihyyaA I updated answer - look for header Update v 0.1 - new code normalize-filenames.js there. I think it answers to your comment in all but for that part about restoring file names. About restoring filenames - yes you can do it but I need to think a for a while how. I'll add Update v 0.2 later. No, it won't change source code for normalize-filenames.js . But it will add another batch programm to parse mapping and change filenames accordingly. I need to think for a while how to write it.

Comment: you are amazing . Thank you very much I'll be waiting .

Comment: you are amazing . Thank you very much I'll be waiting .   and if you update the file can you put "-" > "_" because "-" has meaning in batch file (just if you update the file "I don't want to bother you more than this") Thanks.

Comment: Im Sorry But  when i put "cscript //NoLogo normalize-filenames-v0.1.js "./a" "./b" it works correctly but if i put "cscript //NoLogo normalize-filenames-v0.1.js "./a" "./b" 0 F  (if F>2 argument control in Zeros become 2) (it's ok with F>10)

Comment: I'm sorry i mean that with "normalize-filenames.js 0 3" give input-03 .........input-09 " (i think is bug by default should be input-3 .........input-9) (the reason i put the Numbers as variable & cmd don't know 1... if i put 01... )  -- about your question It's ok if you have with Argument of zeros just Remove it & Put default option without zeros after input_ (input_1 .....input_9) and Thanks again. (im sorry about my english)

Comment: i'll be happy if you put external file for just agrument of zeros (rename) wth puting the path of files (name with numbers llike "hg 1.mp4" "IGH 1 - hg.mp4" or somthing like that) (and you can give short name of normalize-filenames.js (i don't want to change it))

Comment: Thank you very much . it's work correctly . About your question . I think I'll need the support of non-English sometime (encoding of amines (japan))   so I'll be thankful if you look at it sometime you want (just if you have time free) . & about "glue.cmd" can you give me simple usage if I linked the two files (normalize-filenames.js,restore-filenames.cmd) Thank you very much.

Comment: It would be difficult to explain without chat... unfortunately you don't have enough points for chat. Ok. I'll try to explain anyway. GLUE.CMD is EXAMPLE of how you could automate your workflow. It's full fo parts that are just waiting to be vandalized, swapped placed and adjucted. You can read it - I tried to write comments in a readable way. Any line that starts with :: or with REM is comment - it doesn't do any program stuff it's just there for programmer to read it.

Comment: What that glue example does in a nutshell - is 1). you define absolute paths to all programs, and path to folder where your source files lie... 2) Then you continue making small steps towards victory and if you see that your step failed you print panic ECHO MESSAGE ERROR that explains what and where broke and then you kill script (EXIT /B 1) - because really - if one of previous steps failed - other don't make any sence...

Comment: 3) Your first small step in that example is to create new empty folders tmpB and tmpC. If they existed before you started GLUE - then you delete them and create anew.

Comment: 4) you run (normalize-filenames.js) and save mapping file to (mappingFile.txt) Normalized files are created in tmpB 5) Now you can your changes with normalized files tmpB/input_1...tmpB/input_100 - those weird ECHO DO SOME USEFUL STUFF WITH TMPB - you should change those to your own script that change them. 6) Now that tmpB has awesome files with awesome contents and normalized filenames, you want to restore their names... so you want to run (restore-filenames) and fill tmpC with awesome files with old filenames. But before really doing anything you want to see what would be new filenames.

Comment: 7) An the last block (which you perhaps would like to delete before first run of CLUE.CMD) will be li 'OK, I really liked new file names that I saw in step-6' so you will do everything the same as it was in (step-6) exept that this time you really create awesome files with old names in tmpC. 8) Profit. Well, actually you could add here something more - like copy folder tmpC to folder, and then delete tmpB and tmpC and perhaps mappingFile - but that's already a matter of taste. It's up to your tastes, skills and fantasy here now.

Comment: Take a notice - for this organization of workflow to be useful, you must automate (step-5). I remember that you do some processing with normalized files... so it must be automated or GLUE doen't make any sense..

Comment: By the way - here is a compact but interesting tutorial for batch processing: http://steve-jansen.github.io/guides/windows-batch-scripting/index.html - what I learned about pure batch, I learned there in a previous week. So if you want to automate (step-5) then perhaps that tutorial will help to teach you how to do it. Of course - your tools for processing normalized files should be compatible with cmd... if those work through Graphical User Interface only... then all that glue makes no sense...

Comment: OK . Thank you very much i will read the comments ..... and I will be looking forward to chat with you if you don't mind....

Comment: about the link i'll be read the thread and i don't think i'll be understan so much . (im arabic).

Comment: I'm Sorry I have new problem with "restore-filenames.cmd" : is the extensions . (The names of files can be the same but the extensions they changed (from .flv .mp4 .mkv to .mkv or any extension else) - so can you solve that ? -(by sending just name of file without extensions to mapping.txt Or ....)  - And something else i see that files in files in tempB linked by mapping.txt with The sources files (if i changed something in source folder (Folder a in glue.cmd)) .   can you solve that (want files linked by Origins Names only) (because the source folder is temp folder) . THANK YOU VERY MUCH.

Comment: I wanted to ask: is it OK if I completely rewrite my post? Much of it's present information and source code would be completely lost. If it's OK, I will post set a slightly different set of utilities - those should handy for your problem (be it first iteration or last ^ ^).

Comment: OK it's ok if that what you see ( but realy i like that files ). and i wanted to update my last comment but i forg et that .it is about The second part of question .you can skkip the last comment because i Found the solution. (i'll delete the comment)

Comment: but if you update the files give the version number to files (i didn't know that you update glue.cmd until today)

Comment: Perhaps I will add few more ideas later (in a coming week), but the framework seem to be set. Also - it would be polite if you could delete comments that became irrelevant. Because as of now it looks like message board, and stackoverflow is not encouraging that ^ ^ It would be useful to talk in chat... but for talking in stackexhange chat you need rep 20+, and your's now is only 6. Do you have any e-mail for contacts? If you are afraid of spammers, you can easily create temporary email. That would be a good way of communicating about your question.

Comment: and can you look about skiping error message in last file after.cmd (mean should works restore name even if not exist all files like 3 from 5 files) it works for the first files but the cmd.exe closes after that.

Answer (score 0):

---

Listing for program **build-mapping-to-normalized-filenames.js** :

```
// - - - - -
//  #magicVars #config

// Purpose of basicOptions: organize set of most basic settings
//                          into a compact object package

var basicOptions = {

    // Fist things first -
    // "scriptName" will be important for error messages.
    // Because when you debug a pipeline of scripts, it is always
    // crucial to know - which program in pipeline of 10 utilities
    // throws that cryptic stderr message "error: not enough arguments".
    // I mean huh? Was that calc-tool.js? Or sort-tool.js? Go figure...
    scriptName: WScript.ScriptName.toString(),

    // What kind of End Of Line sequence
    // (they call it New Line sometimes too)
    // you prefer when using outputToolbox?
    eolStdOut: '\r\n',
    eolStdErr: '\r\n',

    // Those are all possible errorCodes that this script
    // was designed to fail with.
    // You can define other error codes.
    // Those SHOULD be integer (not strings).
    // Code noErrors = 0 is indication that script finished without errors.
    errorCodes: {
        noErrors: 0,
        badArguments: 1,
        badGettingFileList: 2
    }

};



// - - - - -

//  thisOptions

// Purpose of thisOptions: organize set of hard-coded
//                         normalisation settings
//                         into a compact object package

var thisOptions = {
    normNameBefore: 'input_',
    normNameAfter: ''
}



// - - - - -
//  outputToolbox depends on
//      basicOptions && WScript

// Purpose of outputToolbox: organize in one group
//                           functions that are used to
//                           output chars or messages to stdout or stderr

var outputToolbox = {

    // Syntactic sugar for printing exact set of chars to stdout.
    print: function( data ) {

        // For this script to output UTF characters correctly, program must
        // run under /U switch - like
        // cscript /U //NoLogo program-name-here.js arg1 arg2
        WScript.StdOut.Write( data );
    },

    // Syntactic sugar for printing one line to stdout.
    // terminated with your preferred line-terminator.
    printLine: function( data ) {
        outputToolbox.print( data );
        outputToolbox.print( basicOptions.eolStdOut );
    },

    // Syntactic sugar for printing exact set of chars to stderr.
    printErr: function( data ) {
        WScript.StdErr.Write( data );
    },

    // Syntactic sugar for printing one line to stderr
    // terminated with your preferred line-terminator.
    printErrLine: function( data ) {
        outputToolbox.printErr( data );
        outputToolbox.printErr( basicOptions.eolStdErr );
    },

    // Syntactic sugar for printing one line to stderr
    // prepended with meaningful script name (that is useful for debug)
    // terminated with your preferred line-terminator.
    printErrMessage: function( data ) {
        outputToolbox.printErr( basicOptions.scriptName + ' failed' );
        outputToolbox.printErr( data );
        outputToolbox.printErr( basicOptions.eolStdErr );
    },

    // Syntactic sugar for printing one line to stderr
    // prepended with meaningful script name (that is useful for debug)
    // terminated with your preferred line-terminator.
    printErrWarning: function( data ) {
        outputToolbox.printErr( 'Warning for ' + basicOptions.scriptName + ': ' );
        outputToolbox.printErr( data );
        outputToolbox.printErr( basicOptions.eolStdErr );
    },

    // Syntactic sugar for printing Error objects
    // catched by throw...catch construction
    printErrCatchedErr: function( e ) {
        outputToolbox.printErrMessage(
            ' - catched error details - ' + e.name + ': ' + e.message
        );
    }

};



// - - - - -
//  flowToolbox depends on
//      WScript

// Purpose of flowToolbox: organize in one group
//                         functions that are used to
//                         control general flow of program

var flowToolbox = {

    // Shortcut to kill this script.
    // When invoked it stops execution.
    die: function ( code ) {
        if ( typeof code === 'undefined' ) {
            code = 0;
        }
        WScript.Quit(code);
    }

};





// - - - - -
// Here is a cleaner alternative: we pollute only name $b.
// Not so easy to type but later, you can easily find all code calls
// dependant on functions from 'basis'.
// '$b' stands for 'library-b' or more exactly - "library named 'basis'"

var $b = {};

$b.print           = outputToolbox.print;
$b.printLine       = outputToolbox.printLine;
$b.printErr        = outputToolbox.printErr;
$b.printErrLine    = outputToolbox.printErrLine;
$b.printErrMessage = outputToolbox.printErrMessage;
$b.printErrWarning = outputToolbox.printErrWarning;

$b.die             = flowToolbox.die;

// ^ You can use those as functions now





// - - - - -
//  $fileListToolbox
//      depends on WScript && ActiveXObject( "Scripting.FileSystemObject" ) && $b

var $fileListToolbox = {

    /*
    *   Input:
    *       any gibberish that is acceptable
    *       for your local version of
    *       Scripting.FileSystemObject
    *       - like
    *           getFileListForFolder( 'C:\' );
    *           getFileListForFolder( 'C:\abc' );
    *           getFileListForFolder( './' );
    *           getFileListForFolder( './abc/../abc/..' );
    *   
    *   Output:
    *       aFileList with format:
    *           empty array
    *           or
    *           array of oFileData
    *               oFileData has format:
    *               {
    *                   fileNameBase:       ...[string],
    *                   fileNameExtension:  ...[string],
    *                   parentAbsolutePath: ...[string]
    *               }
    */
    getFileListForFolder: function( folderSpec )
    {
        var aResult = [];

        var fso    = new ActiveXObject( "Scripting.FileSystemObject" );

        if ( !fso.FolderExists( folderSpec ) ) {
            $b.printErrMessage(' folder="' + folderSpec + '" doesn\'t exist');
            $b.die( basicOptions.errorCodes.badGettingFileList );
        }

        var folder = fso.GetFolder( folderSpec );
        var files  = new Enumerator( folder.files );

        for ( ; !files.atEnd(); files.moveNext() ) {

            var thisFileItem = files.item();
            aResult.push({
                fileNameBase:      fso.GetBaseName(      thisFileItem ),
                fileNameExtension: fso.GetExtensionName( thisFileItem ),

                parentAbsolutePath: (
                    fso.GetParentFolderName(
                        fso.GetAbsolutePathName( thisFileItem )
                    )
                )
            });

        }
        return( aResult );
    },


    /*
    *   Purpose:
    *       Sort files by fileNameBase
    *   
    *   Input:
    *       aFileList
    *           - format is the same
    *           as for function $fileListToolbox.getFileListForFolder
    *   
    *   Output:
    *       - format is the same
    *       as for function $fileListToolbox.getFileListForFolder
    */
    sortFileListByFileNameBaseAsc: function( aFileList ) {

        var fSort = function( a, b ) {
            if ( a.fileNameBase > b.fileNameBase ) {
                return 1;
            }
            if ( a.fileNameBase < b.fileNameBase ) {
                return -1;
            }
            return 0;
        }

        return aFileList.sort( fSort );

    },


    /*
    *   Purpose:
    *       Tool for displaying contents of fileList
    *   
    *   Input:
    *       aFileList
    *           - format is the same
    *           as for function $fileListToolbox.getFileListForFolder
    *   
    *   Sideeffects:
    *       Prints aFileList to the stdout stream
    */
    printFileList: function( aFileList, callbackPrintLine ) {

        if ( typeof callbackPrintLine === 'undefined' ) {
            return;
        }

        var i;
        var L = aFileList.length;
        var elem;
        for ( i = 0; i < L; i++ ) {
            elem = aFileList[i];
            callbackPrintLine();
            callbackPrintLine( 'i: ' + i );
            callbackPrintLine( 'fileNameBase:       ' + elem.fileNameBase );
            callbackPrintLine( 'fileNameExtension:  ' + elem.fileNameExtension );
            callbackPrintLine( 'parentAbsolutePath: ' + elem.parentAbsolutePath );
        }
    }

};

/*
// basic test:
$fileListToolbox.printFileList(
    $fileListToolbox.sortFileListByFileNameBaseAsc(
        $fileListToolbox.getFileListForFolder( 'bTmp' )
    ),
    $b.printLine
);
*/














// - - - - -
//  $mappingEngine

var $mappingEngine = {

    // this is a relic from a more complex fileformat...
    printHeader: function(
        functionPrintChars
    ) {
    },

    printBasicFilePair: function(
        functionPrintChars,
        aFileNameBase, aFileNameExtension,
        bFileNameBase, bFileNameExtension
    ) {
        var eol = '\r\n';

        if ( aFileNameBase.match( /[\r\n]/ ) !== null ) {
            throw new Error(
                'error: bad input: aFileNameBase contains end of line symbols'
            );
        }
        if ( bFileNameBase.match( /[\r\n]/ ) !== null ) {
            throw new Error(
                'error: bad input: bFileNameBase contains end of line symbols'
            );
        }
        if ( aFileNameExtension.match( /[\r\n]/ ) !== null ) {
            throw new Error(
                'error: bad input: aFileNameExtension contains end of line symbols'
            );
        }
        if ( bFileNameExtension.match( /[\r\n]/ ) !== null ) {
            throw new Error(
                'error: bad input: bFileNameExtension contains end of line symbols'
            );
        }

        var ar = [
            'id:1',
            'baseName:'      + aFileNameBase,
            'extensionName:' + aFileNameExtension,
            'id:2',
            'baseName:'      + bFileNameBase,
            'extensionName:' + bFileNameExtension,
            ':',
            ''
        ];
        functionPrintChars( ar.join( eol ) );
    }

};

/*
//basic test:
$mappingEngine.printHeader( $b.print );
$mappingEngine.printBasicFilePair( $b.print, 'abcdef', 'ext', 'input_001', 'txt' );
$mappingEngine.printBasicFilePair( $b.print, 'ghijkl', 'jpg', 'input_002', 'png' );
*/
// it should print to output:
/*
id:1
baseName:abcdef
extensionName:ext
id:2
baseName:input_001
extensionName:txt
:
id:1
baseName:ghijkl
extensionName:jpg
id:2
baseName:input_002
extensionName:png
:

*/





// - - - - -

function generateFAddLeadingZeroes( minimumLength, startFrom ) {

    if ( typeof minimumLength === 'undefined' ) {
        minimumLength = 0;
    }
    if ( typeof startFrom === 'undefined' ) {
        startFrom = 0;
    }

    minimumLength = parseInt( minimumLength ) - 1;
    startFrom     = parseInt( startFrom );

    var fAddLeadingZeroes = function( i, L ) {

        i += startFrom;
        L += startFrom - 1;

        var sResult = i.toString();

        if ( minimumLength > 0 ) {

            var level = 0;
            var tmpL = L;
            while (
                ( tmpL = parseInt( tmpL / 10 ) ) >= 1
            ) {
                ++level;
            }

            level = Math.max( level, minimumLength );

            var iLength = sResult.length;
            while ( iLength <= level-- ) {
                sResult = '0' + sResult;
            }
        }

        return sResult;
    }
    return fAddLeadingZeroes;
}





// - - - - -
var $thisArguments = {

    getArgumentsObj: function() {

        return WScript.Arguments;


        // mockup for tests in browser
        /*
        var testArr = [1,2,3,4,5];
        var mockupArguments = function( i ) {
            return testArr[i];
        };
        mockupArguments.length = testArr.length;
        return mockupArguments;
        */
    },

    printErrorMessageAndDie: function( meaningfulPart ) {
        $b.printErrMessage(
            ' - problem when ' +
            'parsing command-line arguments (options): ' +
            ''
        );
        $b.die( basicOptions.errorCodes.badArguments );
    },

    getArgumentsDummy: function() {
        return {
            folder:       'C:\abc',
            minNOfDigits: 0,
            countStart:   1
        };
    },

    print: function( argumentsObject ) {
        $b.printErrLine( 'folder:       ' + argumentsObject.folder       );
        $b.printErrLine( 'minNOfDigits: ' + argumentsObject.minNOfDigits );
        $b.printErrLine( 'countStart:   ' + argumentsObject.countStart   );
    },

    // We don't use any flags it this script...
    /*
    isThereAFlagInArguments: function( inString ) {
        var normalizedEthalon = inString.toString().toLowerCase();
        var objArgs = $thisArguments.getArgumentsObj();
        var i;
        var L = objArgs.length;
        for ( i = 2; i < L; i++ ) {
            var normalizedArgument = objArgs( i ).toString().toLowerCase();
            if ( normalizedEthalon === normalizedArgument ) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    },
    */

    getArguments: {

        folder: function() {
            var rR = '';
            var objArgs = $thisArguments.getArgumentsObj();
            if ( objArgs.length < 1 ) {
                $b.printErrMessage(
                    ' - reason: not enough arguments, ' +
                    'you MUST to provide at least 1 argument, ' +
                    'but ammount of arguments you provided ' +
                    'only: ' + objArgs.length
                );
                $b.die( basicOptions.errorCodes.badArguments );
            }

            rR = objArgs(0);

            var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
            rR = fso.GetAbsolutePathName( rR );

            return rR;
        },

        minNOfDigits: function() {
            var rR = '0';
            var objArgs = $thisArguments.getArgumentsObj();

            if ( objArgs.length >= 2 ) {
                rR = objArgs(1);
            }

            var intRR = parseInt( rR );

            // test for NaN
            if ( intRR !== intRR ) {
                $b.printErrMessage(
                    ' - reason: bad argument 2, ' +
                    'you MUST to provide non-negative integer, ' +
                    'but you provided non-integer: ' +
                    '[' + ( typeof rR ) + ']' +
                    ' "' + rR + '"' +
                    ''
                );
                $b.die( basicOptions.errorCodes.badArguments );
            }

            // test for negative
            if ( intRR < 0 ) {
                $b.printErrMessage(
                    ' - reason: bad argument 2, ' +
                    'you MUST to provide non-negative integer, ' +
                    'but you provided negtive integer: ' +
                    '[' + ( typeof rR ) + ']' +
                    ' "' + rR + '"' +
                    ''
                );
                $b.die( basicOptions.errorCodes.badArguments );
            }

            rR = intRR;

            return rR;
        },

        countStart: function() {
            var rR = '1';
            var objArgs = $thisArguments.getArgumentsObj();
            if ( objArgs.length >= 3 ) {
                rR = objArgs(2);
            }

            var intRR = parseInt( rR );

            // test for NaN
            if ( intRR !== intRR ) {
                $b.printErrMessage(
                    ' - reason: bad argument 3, ' +
                    'you MUST to provide non-negative integer, ' +
                    'but you provided non-integer: ' +
                    '[' + ( typeof rR ) + ']' +
                    ' "' + rR + '"' +
                    ''
                );
                $b.die( basicOptions.errorCodes.badArguments );
            }

            // test for negative
            if ( intRR < 0 ) {
                $b.printErrMessage(
                    ' - reason: bad argument 3, ' +
                    'you MUST to provide non-negative integer, ' +
                    'but you provided negtive integer: ' +
                    '[' + ( typeof rR ) + ']' +
                    ' "' + rR + '"' +
                    ''
                );
                $b.die( basicOptions.errorCodes.badArguments );
            }

            rR = intRR;

            return rR;
        }

    },

    getArgumentsAll: function() {
        var $get = $thisArguments.getArguments;

        var rR = {
            folder:       $get.folder(),
            minNOfDigits: $get.minNOfDigits(),
            countStart:   $get.countStart()
        };

        return rR;
    }

};

var $a = $thisArguments;





// - - - - -

function main() {

    var $inputOptions = $a.getArgumentsAll();
    $b.printErrLine();
    $b.printErrLine(
        'Arguments for ' + basicOptions.scriptName +
        ' are interpreted this way:'
    );
    $a.print( $inputOptions );
    $b.printErrLine();

    try {
        var aFileList = $fileListToolbox.getFileListForFolder( $inputOptions.folder );
    } catch (e) {
        $b.printErrMessage(
            ' - problems while trying ' +
            'to get list of files from folder: ' +
            $inputOptions.folder
        );
        $b.die( basicOptions.errorCodes.badGettingFileList );
        return;
    }
    aFileList = $fileListToolbox.sortFileListByFileNameBaseAsc( aFileList );

    // addLeadingZeroes
    // is a function now.
    // You can see what arguments it requires
    // and output it produces in source for
    // generateFAddLeadingZeroes
    // function.
    var addLeadingZeroes = generateFAddLeadingZeroes(
        $inputOptions.minNOfDigits,
        $inputOptions.countStart
    );

    var normNameBefore = thisOptions.normNameBefore;
    var normNameAfter  = thisOptions.normNameAfter;

    var i;
    var L = aFileList.length;
    for ( i = 0; i < L; i++ ) {

        var elem = aFileList[i];

        var aBase      = elem.fileNameBase;
        var aExtension = elem.fileNameExtension;

        var count      = addLeadingZeroes( i, L );

        var bBase      = normNameBefore + count + normNameAfter;
        var bExtension = aExtension;

        $mappingEngine.printBasicFilePair(
            $b.print,
            aBase, aExtension,
            bBase, bExtension
        );
    }

    $b.printErr( 'Script ' + basicOptions.scriptName + ' - finished!' );

};

main();
```

Answer (score 0):

---

Listing for program **map-filenames.js** :

```
// - - - - -
//  #magicVars #config

// Purpose of basicOptions: organize set of most basic settings
//                          into a compact object package

var basicOptions = {

    // Fist things first -
    // "scriptName" will be important for error messages.
    // Because when you debug a pipeline of scripts, it is always
    // crucial to know - which program in pipeline of 10 utilities
    // throws that cryptic stderr message "error: not enough arguments".
    // I mean huh? Was that calc-tool.js? Or sort-tool.js? Go figure...
    scriptName: WScript.ScriptName.toString(),

    // What kind of End Of Line sequence
    // (they call it New Line sometimes too)
    // you prefer when using outputToolbox?
    eolStdOut: '\r\n',
    eolStdErr: '\r\n',

    // Those are all possible errorCodes that this script
    // was designed to fail with.
    // You can define other error codes.
    // Those SHOULD be integer (not strings).
    // Code noErrors = 0 is indication that script finished without errors.
    errorCodes: {
        noErrors: 0,
        badArguments: 1,
        badCopy: 2,
        badParsing: 3,
        badGettingFileList: 4
    }

};



// - - - - -



// - - - - -
//  outputToolbox depends on
//      basicOptions && WScript

// Purpose of outputToolbox: organize in one group
//                           functions that are used to
//                           output chars or messages to stdout or stderr

var outputToolbox = {

    // Syntactic sugar for printing exact set of chars to stdout.
    print: function( data ) {

        // For this script to output UTF characters correctly, program must
        // run under /U switch - like
        // cscript /U //NoLogo program-name-here.js arg1 arg2
        WScript.StdOut.Write( data );
    },

    // Syntactic sugar for printing one line to stdout.
    // terminated with your preferred line-terminator.
    printLine: function( data ) {
        outputToolbox.print( data );
        outputToolbox.print( basicOptions.eolStdOut );
    },

    // Syntactic sugar for printing exact set of chars to stderr.
    printErr: function( data ) {
        WScript.StdErr.Write( data );
    },

    // Syntactic sugar for printing one line to stderr
    // terminated with your preferred line-terminator.
    printErrLine: function( data ) {
        outputToolbox.printErr( data );
        outputToolbox.printErr( basicOptions.eolStdErr );
    },

    // Syntactic sugar for printing one line to stderr
    // prepended with meaningful script name (that is useful for debug)
    // terminated with your preferred line-terminator.
    printErrMessage: function( data ) {
        outputToolbox.printErr( basicOptions.scriptName + ' failed' );
        outputToolbox.printErr( data );
        outputToolbox.printErr( basicOptions.eolStdErr );
    },

    // Syntactic sugar for printing one line to stderr
    // prepended with meaningful script name (that is useful for debug)
    // terminated with your preferred line-terminator.
    printErrWarning: function( data ) {
        outputToolbox.printErr( 'Warning for ' + basicOptions.scriptName + ': ' );
        outputToolbox.printErr( data );
        outputToolbox.printErr( basicOptions.eolStdErr );
    },

    // Syntactic sugar for printing Error objects
    // catched by throw...catch construction
    printErrCatchedErr: function( e ) {
        outputToolbox.printErrMessage(
            ' - catched error details - ' + e.name + ': ' + e.message
        );
    }

};



// - - - - -
//  flowToolbox depends on
//      WScript

// Purpose of flowToolbox: organize in one group
//                         functions that are used to
//                         control general flow of program

var flowToolbox = {

    // Shortcut to kill this script.
    // When invoked it stops execution.
    die: function ( code ) {
        if ( typeof code === 'undefined' ) {
            code = 0;
        }
        WScript.Quit(code);
    }

};





// - - - - -
// Here is a cleaner alternative: we pollute only name $b.
// Not so easy to type but later, you can easily find all code calls
// dependant on functions from 'basis'.
// '$b' stands for 'library-b' or more exactly - "library named 'basis'"

var $b = {};

$b.print           = outputToolbox.print;
$b.printLine       = outputToolbox.printLine;
$b.printErr        = outputToolbox.printErr;
$b.printErrLine    = outputToolbox.printErrLine;
$b.printErrMessage = outputToolbox.printErrMessage;
$b.printErrWarning = outputToolbox.printErrWarning;

$b.die             = flowToolbox.die;

// ^ You can use those as functions now





// - - - - -
//  $fileListToolbox
//      depends on WScript && ActiveXObject( "Scripting.FileSystemObject" ) && $b

var $fileListToolbox = {

    /*
    *   Input:
    *       any gibberish that is acceptable
    *       for your local version of
    *       Scripting.FileSystemObject
    *       - like
    *           getFileListForFolder( 'C:\' );
    *           getFileListForFolder( 'C:\abc' );
    *           getFileListForFolder( './' );
    *           getFileListForFolder( './abc/../abc/..' );
    *   
    *   Output:
    *       aFileList with format:
    *           empty array
    *           or
    *           array of oFileData
    *               oFileData has format:
    *               {
    *                   fileNameBase:       ...[string],
    *                   fileNameExtension:  ...[string],
    *                   parentAbsolutePath: ...[string]
    *               }
    */
    getFileListForFolder: function( folderSpec )
    {
        var aResult = [];

        var fso    = new ActiveXObject( "Scripting.FileSystemObject" );

        if ( !fso.FolderExists( folderSpec ) ) {
            $b.printErrMessage(' folder="' + folderSpec + '" doesn\'t exist');
            $b.die( basicOptions.errorCodes.badGettingFileList );
        }

        var folder = fso.GetFolder( folderSpec );
        var files  = new Enumerator( folder.files );

        for ( ; !files.atEnd(); files.moveNext() ) {

            var thisFileItem = files.item();
            aResult.push({
                fileNameBase:      fso.GetBaseName(      thisFileItem ),
                fileNameExtension: fso.GetExtensionName( thisFileItem ),

                parentAbsolutePath: (
                    fso.GetParentFolderName(
                        fso.GetAbsolutePathName( thisFileItem )
                    )
                )
            });

        }
        return( aResult );
    },


    /*
    *   Purpose:
    *       Sort files by fileNameBase
    *   
    *   Input:
    *       aFileList
    *           - format is the same
    *           as for function $fileListToolbox.getFileListForFolder
    *   
    *   Output:
    *       - format is the same
    *       as for function $fileListToolbox.getFileListForFolder
    */
    sortFileListByFileNameBaseAsc: function( aFileList ) {

        var fSort = function( a, b ) {
            if ( a.fileNameBase > b.fileNameBase ) {
                return 1;
            }
            if ( a.fileNameBase < b.fileNameBase ) {
                return -1;
            }
            return 0;
        }

        return aFileList.sort( fSort );

    },

    /*
        Output:
            false
                when no results
            oFileData
                when result found
    */
    getAnyFileWithBaseName: function( baseName, aFileList ) {

        var i;
        var L = aFileList.length;
        for ( i = 0; i < L; i++ ) {
            var a = aFileList[i];
            if ( a.fileNameBase === baseName ) {
                return a;
            }
        }

        return false;
    },


    /*
    *   Purpose:
    *       Tool for displaying contents of fileList
    *   
    *   Input:
    *       aFileList
    *           - format is the same
    *           as for function $fileListToolbox.getFileListForFolder
    *   
    *   Sideeffects:
    *       Prints aFileList to the stdout stream
    */
    printFileList: function( aFileList, callbackPrintLine ) {

        if ( typeof callbackPrintLine === 'undefined' ) {
            return;
        }

        var i;
        var L = aFileList.length;
        var elem;
        for ( i = 0; i < L; i++ ) {
            elem = aFileList[i];
            callbackPrintLine();
            callbackPrintLine( 'i: ' + i );
            callbackPrintLine( 'fileNameBase:       ' + elem.fileNameBase );
            callbackPrintLine( 'fileNameExtension:  ' + elem.fileNameExtension );
            callbackPrintLine( 'parentAbsolutePath: ' + elem.parentAbsolutePath );
        }
    }

};

/*
// basic test:
$fileListToolbox.printFileList(
    $fileListToolbox.sortFileListByFileNameBaseAsc(
        $fileListToolbox.getFileListForFolder( 'bTmp' )
    ),
    $b.printLine
);
*/
/*
// test for fuzzy search only by file base name:
$fileListToolbox.printFileList(
    $fileListToolbox.sortFileListByFileNameBaseAsc(
        $fileListToolbox.getFileListForFolder( 'bTmp' )
    ),
    $b.printLine
);

var fuzzy = $fileListToolbox.getAnyFileWithBaseName(
    'input_1',
    $fileListToolbox.getFileListForFolder( 'bTmp' )
);

$b.printLine( 'fuzzy.fileNameBase:      ' + fuzzy.fileNameBase      );
$b.printLine( 'fuzzy.fileNameExtension: ' + fuzzy.fileNameExtension );
*/











// $streamToolbox

var $streamToolbox = {

    // when end of line returns '' (aka empty string)
    getChar: function() {
        if ( WScript.StdIn.AtEndOfStream ) {
            return '';
        }
        return WScript.StdIn.Read(1);
    },

    // tests show that for Windows 7 it understands terminators
    // CRLF or LF-only
    // when end of line returns '' (aka empty string)
    getLine: function() {
        if ( WScript.StdIn.AtEndOfStream ) {
            return '';
        }
        return WScript.StdIn.ReadLine();
    }

}

var $s = $streamToolbox;

// it could be used like that:
/*
var piece;
while ( ( piece = $s.getLine() ) !== '' ) {

    $b.printLine( 'piece: ' + '>' + piece + '<' );
}
*/









// $thisArguments

var $thisArguments = {

    getArgumentsObj: function() {

        return WScript.Arguments;


        // mockup for tests in browser
        /*
        var testArr = [1,2,3,4,5];
        var mockupArguments = function( i ) {
            return testArr[i];
        };
        mockupArguments.length = testArr.length;
        return mockupArguments;
        */
    },

    printErrorMessageAndDie: function( meaningfulPart ) {
        $b.printErrMessage(
            ' - problem when ' +
            'parsing command-line arguments (options): ' +
            ''
        );
        $b.die( basicOptions.errorCodes.badArguments );
    },

    getArgumentsDummy: function() {
        return {
            direction:            'from-id-2-to-id-1',
            resultExtension:      'auto',
            folderFrom:           'C:\abc',
            folderTo:             'D:\abc',
            mode:                 'training',
            modeForExtensionFrom: 'strict'
        };
    },

    print: function( argumentsObject ) {
        $b.printErrLine( 'folderFrom:           ' + argumentsObject.folderFrom           );
        $b.printErrLine( 'folderTo:             ' + argumentsObject.folderTo             );
        $b.printErrLine( 'direction:            ' + argumentsObject.direction            );
        $b.printErrLine( 'resultExtension:      ' + argumentsObject.resultExtension      );
        $b.printErrLine( 'mode:                 ' + argumentsObject.mode                 );
        $b.printErrLine( 'modeForExtensionFrom: ' + argumentsObject.modeForExtensionFrom );
    },

    isThereAFlagInArguments: function( inString ) {
        var normalizedEthalon = inString.toString().toLowerCase();
        var objArgs = $thisArguments.getArgumentsObj();
        var i;
        var L = objArgs.length;
        for ( i = 2; i < L; i++ ) {
            var normalizedArgument = objArgs( i ).toString().toLowerCase();
            if ( normalizedEthalon === normalizedArgument ) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    },

    getArguments: {

        folderFrom: function() {
            var rR = '';
            var objArgs = $thisArguments.getArgumentsObj();
            if ( objArgs.length < 2 ) {
                $b.printErrMessage(
                    ' - reason: not enough arguments, ' +
                    'you MUST to provide at least 2 arguments, ' +
                    'but ammount of arguments you provided ' +
                    'is only: ' + objArgs.length
                );
                $b.die( basicOptions.errorCodes.badArguments );
            }

            rR = objArgs(0);

            var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
            rR = fso.GetAbsolutePathName( rR );

            return rR;
        },

        folderTo: function() {
            var rR = '';
            var objArgs = $thisArguments.getArgumentsObj();
            if ( objArgs.length < 2 ) {
                $b.printErrMessage(
                    ' - reason: not enough arguments, ' +
                    'you MUST to provide at least 2 arguments, ' +
                    'but ammount of arguments you provided ' +
                    'is only: ' + objArgs.length
                );
                $b.die( basicOptions.errorCodes.badArguments );
            }

            rR = objArgs(1);

            var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
            rR = fso.GetAbsolutePathName( rR );

            return rR;
        },

        direction: function() {
            var rR = 'from-id-1-to-id-2';
            var hasFlag = $thisArguments.isThereAFlagInArguments;
            if ( hasFlag( '/MapFrom2To1' ) ) {
                rR = 'from-id-2-to-id-1';
            }
            return rR;
        },

        resultExtension: function() {
            var rR = 'auto';
            var hasFlag = $thisArguments.isThereAFlagInArguments;
            if ( hasFlag( '/ResultExtension:none' ) ) {
                rR = 'none';
            }
            if ( hasFlag( '/ResultExtension:21' ) ) {
                rR = '21';
            }
            if ( hasFlag( '/ResultExtension:12' ) ) {
                rR = '12';
            }
            if ( hasFlag( '/ResultExtension:2' ) ) {
                rR = '2';
            }
            if ( hasFlag( '/ResultExtension:1' ) ) {
                rR = '1';
            }
            return rR;
        },

        mode: function() {
            var rR = 'training';
            var hasFlag = $thisArguments.isThereAFlagInArguments;
            if ( hasFlag( '/NotTraining' ) ) {
                rR = 'not-training';
            }
            return rR;
        },

        modeForExtensionFrom: function() {
            var rR = 'strict';
            var hasFlag = $thisArguments.isThereAFlagInArguments;
            if ( hasFlag( '/FuzzyExtensionsFrom' ) ) {
                rR = 'fuzzy';
            }
            return rR;
        }

    },

    getArgumentsAll: function() {
        var $get = $thisArguments.getArguments;

        var rR = {
            folderFrom:           $get.folderFrom(),
            folderTo:             $get.folderTo(),
            direction:            $get.direction(),
            resultExtension:      $get.resultExtension(),
            mode:                 $get.mode(),
            modeForExtensionFrom: $get.modeForExtensionFrom()
        };

        return rR;
    }

};

var $a = $thisArguments;

//you can use it like this:
/*
var $inputOptions = $a.getArgumentsAll()
$a.print( $inputOptions );
*/










// $parser

// mockup options for separate testing
/*
var basicOptions = {
    errorCodes: {
        badParsing: 3
    }
};

var $b = {
    printErrMessage: function( a ) { console.log(a); },
    die: function() { throw new Error(); }
};
*/

var $parser = {};

$parser.generateDummyLineReader = function( textBlock ) {
    var lines = textBlock.split( '\r\n' );
    var i = -1;
    var L = lines.length;

    var f = function() {
        i++;
        if ( i >= L ) {
            return '';
        }

        return lines[i];
    }

    return f;
}

$parser.generateDummyInputOptions = function() {
    return {
        direction: '1-to-2',
        resultExtension: '12',
        folderFrom: 'C:\abc',
        folderTo:   'D:\abc'
    }
}

$parser.generateDummyMappingLineReader = function() {
    return $parser.generateDummyLineReader(
        [
            'id:1',
            'baseName:abcdef',
            'extensionName:ext',
            'id:2',
            'baseName:input_001',
            'extensionName:txt',
            ':',
            'id:1',
            'baseName:ghijkl',
            'extensionName:jpg',
            'id:2',
            'baseName:input_002',
            'extensionName:png',
            ':'
        ].join('\r\n')
    );
}

/*
    Remark:
        functionReadNextLine
            must be iterator that returns '' (aka empty string)
            when stream of lines ends
        functionForEachBlockDo must have
        those arguments: 
            - id1Base
            - id1Ext
            - id2Base
            - id2Ext
            - $inputOptions
            - functionCopyFile
        $inputOptions must have properties
        (wherever it mentioned in this block of comments):
            - direction
            - resultExtension
            - folderFrom
            - folderTo
        functionCopyFile must have these arguments
            - folderFrom
            - fileFrom
            - folderTo
            - fileTo
*/
$parser.parseLinesAndForEachBlockDo = function(
    functionReadNextLine,
    functionForEachBlockDo,
    $inputOptions,
    functionCopyFile
) {
    var buffer = null;

    var nOfLine = 0;

    var states = [
        'waitingForId1',
        'waitingForId2',
        'waitingForBase',
        'waitingForExtension',
        'waitingForEndOfGroup'
    ];

    function printErrorMessageAndDie( meaningfulPart ) {
        $b.printErrMessage(
            ' - problem when parsing line ' + nOfLine + ': ' +
            '[' + typeof line + ']' +
            '"' + line + '"' +
            meaningfulPart +
            ''
        );
        $b.die( basicOptions.errorCodes.badParsing );
    }

    var state = 'waitingForId1';

    var line;

    while (
        ( line = functionReadNextLine() ) !== ''
    ) {
        ++nOfLine;

        var arOrNull = line.match( /^([a-zA-Z0-9-]*):(.*)$/ );

        if (
            ( arOrNull === null )
        ) {
            printErrorMessageAndDie(
                'every line in mapping must be either' +
                '"key:value" or ":"'
            );
        }

        var key   = arOrNull[1];
        var value = arOrNull[2];

        if (
            ( value.match( '\r' ) !== null )
        ) {
            printErrorMessageAndDie(
                'if line is ' +
                '"key:value" ' +
                'then it MUST NOT contain \r (CR) symbols ' +
                'exept in terminator'
            );
        }

        if ( state === 'waitingForId1' ) {
            if (
                ( key === 'id' )
                &&
                ( value === '1' )
            ) {
                buffer = {};
                buffer.nowGroup = {
                    id: 1
                };
                state = 'waitingForBase';
                continue;
            } else {
                printErrorMessageAndDie(
                    'but this line must be "id:1"'
                );
            }
        }

        if ( state === 'waitingForBase' ) {
            if (
                ( key === 'baseName' )
            ) {
                buffer.nowGroup.base = value;
                state = 'waitingForExtension';
                continue;
            } else {
                printErrorMessageAndDie(
                    'but this line must be "baseName:...anything-here..."'
                );
            }
        }

        if ( state === 'waitingForExtension' ) {
            if (
                ( key === 'extensionName' )
            ) {
                buffer.nowGroup.ext = value;
                if ( buffer.nowGroup.id === 1 ) {
                    state = 'waitingForId2';
                } else {
                    state = 'waitingForEndOfGroup';
                }
                continue;
            } else {
                printErrorMessageAndDie(
                    'but this line must be "extensionName:...anything-here..."'
                );
            }
        }

        if ( state === 'waitingForId2' ) {
            if (
                ( key === 'id' )
                &&
                ( value === '2' )
            ) {
                buffer.group1 = {
                    base: buffer.nowGroup.base,
                    ext: buffer.nowGroup.ext
                }
                buffer.nowGroup = {
                    id: 2
                };
                state = 'waitingForBase';
                continue;
            } else {
                printErrorMessageAndDie(
                    'but this line must be "id:2"'
                );
            }
        }

        if ( state === 'waitingForEndOfGroup' ) {
            if (
                ( key === '' )
                &&
                ( value === '' )
            ) {
                buffer.group2 = {
                    base: buffer.nowGroup.base,
                    ext: buffer.nowGroup.ext
                }

                functionForEachBlockDo(
                    buffer.group1.base,
                    buffer.group1.ext,
                    buffer.group2.base,
                    buffer.group2.ext,
                    $inputOptions,
                    functionCopyFile
                );
                buffer = null;

                state = 'waitingForId1';
                continue;
            } else {
                printErrorMessageAndDie(
                    'but this line must be ":"'
                );
            }
        }

    }

    if ( buffer !== null ) {
        printErrorMessageAndDie(
            'dangling state (not all properties group are defined) - ' + state
        );
    }
}
/*
// test
// can be tested in for browser with only $parser object
$parser.parseLinesAndForEachBlockDo(
    $parser.generateDummyMappingLineReader(),
    function( a, b, c, d ) {
        console.log( 'a:', a, 'b:', b, 'c:', c, 'd:', d );
    }
);
*/

/*
    Remark:
        $inputOptions must have properties:
            - direction
            - resultExtension
            - folderFrom
            - folderTo

*/
$parser.reactionOnGoodParsedBlock = function(
    id1Base, id1Ext,
    id2Base, id2Ext,
    $inputOptions,
    functionCopyFile
) {
    function glueExtensionToFileName(
        fileName, extension
    ) {
        fileName  = fileName.toString();
        extension = extension.toString();
        if ( extension.length > 0 ) {
            extension = '.' + extension;
        }
        return fileName + extension;
    }

    var folderFrom = $inputOptions.folderFrom;
    var folderTo   = $inputOptions.folderTo;

    if ( $inputOptions.modeForExtensionFrom === 'fuzzy' ) {

        var tmpFromBase = id1Base;
        if ( $inputOptions.direction == 'from-id-2-to-id-1' ) {
            tmpFromBase = id2Base;
        }

        var fuzzyFile = $fileListToolbox.getAnyFileWithBaseName(
            tmpFromBase,
            $fileListToolbox.getFileListForFolder( folderFrom )
        );

        if ( fuzzyFile !== false ) {
            if ( $inputOptions.direction == 'from-id-2-to-id-1' ) {
                id2Ext = fuzzyFile.fileNameExtension;
            } else {
                id1Ext = fuzzyFile.fileNameExtension;
            }
        }

    }

    var fromSet = { base: id1Base, ext: id1Ext };
    var toSet   = { base: id2Base, ext: id2Ext };

    if ( $inputOptions.direction == 'from-id-2-to-id-1' ) {
        fromSet = { base: id2Base, ext: id2Ext };
        toSet   = { base: id1Base, ext: id1Ext };
    }

    if ( $inputOptions.resultExtension === '21' ) {
        toSet.ext = glueExtensionToFileName( id2Ext, id1Ext );
    }
    if ( $inputOptions.resultExtension === '12' ) {
        toSet.ext = glueExtensionToFileName( id1Ext, id2Ext );
    }
    if ( $inputOptions.resultExtension === '2' ) {
        toSet.ext = id2Ext;
    }
    if ( $inputOptions.resultExtension === '1' ) {
        toSet.ext = id1Ext;
    }
    if ( $inputOptions.resultExtension === 'none' ) {
        toSet.ext = '';
    }

    var fileFrom = glueExtensionToFileName( fromSet.base, fromSet.ext );
    var fileTo   = glueExtensionToFileName( toSet.base,   toSet.ext   );

    functionCopyFile(
        folderFrom, fileFrom,
        folderTo,   fileTo
    );
}
/*
// test
// can be tested in for browser with only $parser object
$parser.reactionOnGoodParsedBlock(
    'originalA', 'extA',
    'originalB', 'extB',
    {
        direction: 'from-id-2-to-id-1',
        resultExtension: 'auto',
        folderFrom: 'C:\abc',
        folderTo:   'D:\abc'
    },
    function(
        folderFrom, fileFrom,
        folderTo,   fileTo
    ) {
        console.log(
            'folderFrom:', folderFrom,
            'fileFrom:',   fileFrom,
            'folderTo:',   folderTo,
            'fileTo:',     fileTo
        );
    }
);
// expected result:
// folderFrom: C:abc fileFrom: originalA.extA folderTo: D:abc fileTo: originalB.extB
*/






var $copyFileToolbox = {

    copyFileTraining: function(
        folderFrom, fileFrom,
        folderTo,   fileTo
    ) {
        var fso = new ActiveXObject( "Scripting.FileSystemObject" );
        if ( !fso.FolderExists( folderFrom ) ) {
            $b.printErrWarning('folderFrom="' + folderFrom + '" doesn\'t exist');
        }
        if ( !fso.FolderExists( folderTo ) ) {
            $b.printErrWarning('folderTo="' + folderTo + '" doesn\'t exist');
        }

        var pathFrom = fso.BuildPath( folderFrom, fileFrom );
        var pathTo   = fso.BuildPath( folderTo,   fileTo   );

        if ( !fso.FileExists( pathFrom ) ) {
            $b.printErrLine();
            $b.printErrWarning('no source file found, script looking for it at pathFrom="' + pathFrom + '" - this file doesn\'t exist');
        }
        if ( fso.FileExists( pathTo ) ) {
            $b.printErrLine();
            $b.printErrWarning('be advised - there was found a file at destination for copy command, and in "NotTraining" mode you will overwrite file at pathTo="' + pathTo + '"');
        }

        $b.printLine( '' );
        $b.printLine( 'Training mode: you ask to copy file' );
        $b.printLine( 'from: ' + pathFrom );
        $b.printLine( '\\/' );
        $b.printLine( 'to:   ' + pathTo );
    },

    copyFile: function(
        folderFrom, fileFrom,
        folderTo,   fileTo
    ) {
        var fso = new ActiveXObject( "Scripting.FileSystemObject" );
        if ( !fso.FolderExists( folderFrom ) ) {
            $b.printErrMessage(' folderFrom="' + folderFrom + '" doesn\'t exist');
            $b.die( basicOptions.errorCodes.badCopy );
        }
        if ( !fso.FolderExists( folderTo ) ) {
            $b.printErrMessage (' folderTo="' + folderTo + '" doesn\'t exist');
            $b.die( basicOptions.errorCodes.badCopy );
        }

        var pathFrom = fso.BuildPath( folderFrom, fileFrom );
        var pathTo   = fso.BuildPath( folderTo,   fileTo   );

        if ( !fso.FileExists( pathFrom ) ) {
            $b.printErrMessage(' no source file found, script looking for it at pathFrom="' + pathFrom + '" doesn\'t exist');
            $b.die( basicOptions.errorCodes.badCopy );
        }

        fso.copyFile( pathFrom, pathTo, true );
    }

}

var $c = $copyFileToolbox;

// you can use it as:
/*
$c.copyFileTraining(
    './', '123.txt',
    'b',  '345.txt'
);
*/
// you will have a lot of problems testing if filename is unicode
// only way that I found for Windows 7 is to pass filename as stdin
// from some file (perhaps any streaming from file works ok here...)
// and yes, test shows that it works...






function main() {

    var $inputOptions = $a.getArgumentsAll();
    $b.printErrLine();
    $b.printErrLine(
        'Arguments for ' + basicOptions.scriptName +
        ' are interpreted this way:'
    );
    $a.print( $inputOptions );
    $b.printErrLine();

    var fCopyFile = $c.copyFileTraining;
    if ( $inputOptions.mode === 'not-training' ) {
        fCopyFile = $c.copyFile;
    }

    /*
    var fuzzy = $fileListToolbox.getAnyFileWithBaseName(
        'input_1',
        $fileListToolbox.getFileListForFolder( 'bTmp' )
    );
    */

    $parser.parseLinesAndForEachBlockDo(
        $s.getLine,
        $parser.reactionOnGoodParsedBlock,
        $inputOptions,
        fCopyFile
    );

    $b.printErr( 'Script ' + basicOptions.scriptName + ' - finished!' );
};

main();
```